# Accepting words from the command prompt and converting to list of strings

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to write a code in DrRacket that accepts a multiple words from the command prompt and does converts them to a list of string. For eg. if I enter **hello how do you do** in the prompt, it should convert it into a list **'("hello" "how" "do" "you" "do")**. Is it possible in DrRacket?

i tried this:
    (define inp-lst (read))

On running this code, an input bar is shown in the command promt. but when i enter the above line, the value of inp-lst turns out to be just **'hello**. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, type your input between quotes, like this:

```
(define inp-lst (read))
"hello how do you do"
```

Now, you can create a list of strings doing this:

```
(regexp-split #px" " inp-lst)
> '("hello" "how" "do" "you" "do")
```

**EDIT :**

As has been pointed out in the comments, `read-line` might be a better alternative:

```
(define inp-lst (read-line))
(regexp-split #px" " inp-lst)
> '("hello" "how" "do" "you" "do")
```

Using `read-line`, you don't need to surround the typed text with quotes.

Comment: `(read)` doesn't seem to work for me... I had to do `(require readline/readline)` then do `(readline "Input: ")` to get a prompt.. EDIT: nvm, but readline is probably more what Rajesh is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The 'read' function reads one expression which in your case it the single symbol 'hello.'  Your intention is to read one line, terminated by #\newline, get a single string and then split it by #\space.  Try 'read-line'

Comment: Yes. When i run (define inp-lst (read-line)) , and enter a line in the prompt, say **hello world** , the value of inp-lst is now **"hello world"**

Comment: Perfect!  Now you can split it into the 'tokens' separated by #\space.